# Atributo não definido em um objeto Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estou fazendo umas coisinhas em Vue. E estou com um problema aqui. Aparentemente tem um erro aqui e eu não faço ideia do que está errado. O console diz que titulo não foi definido.

```
var cadastro = new Vue({
    el:'#cadastro',
    data:{
        pagina:0,
        titulo:["Dados Pessoais", "Endereço", "Curso"],
        titulo_atual: titulo[this.pagina]
    },
    methods:{
        passarPagina: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            this.pagina++;
        },

        voltarPagina: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            this.pagina--;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Um palpite, tente `titulo_atual: this.titulo[this.pagina]`

Comment: Agora aparece que this.pagina é quem está indefinido

Comment: Outro palpite, mas tente trocar `this.pagina++;` por `this.data.pagina++;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui:

```
titulo_atual: titulo[this.pagina]
```

O `this` nesse contexto não é o objeto do tipo `Vue` que está sendo criado, e sim o `this` externo (que depende do contexto, provavelmente é `window`). Você pode resolver isso usando uma propriedade computada:

```
var cadastro = new Vue({
    el:'#cadastro',
    data:{
        pagina:0,
        titulo:["Dados Pessoais", "Endereço", "Curso"]
    },
    computed: {
        titulo_atual: function() {
            return this.titulo[this.pagina];
        }
    },
    methods:{
        passarPagina: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            this.pagina++;
        },

        voltarPagina: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            this.pagina--;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Esqueci das propriedades computadas ahah. Muito obrigado amigo!!